# Uncaught Reference Error: validateform is not definded

Tags: javascript

The code is very simple. But this is the first thing off this kind that I am doing, and I simply do not understand what it is that I am doing wrong.
Also this is the raw code straight from OCR.

This is GCSE computing coursework. I don't have to fix it, but I don't know how I'm supposed to test the stuff I'm going to add without the base code working.

```
<head>
    <title>Exam entry</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm(document) {
            var result = true;
            var msg = "";
            if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == "") {
                msg += "You must enter your name \n";
                document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
                document.getElementById(‘name’).style.color = "red";
                result = false;
            }
            if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value == "") {
                msg += "You must enter the subject \n";
                document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
                document.getElementById(‘subject’).style.color = "red";
                result = false;
            }
            if (msg == "") {
                return result;
            } {
                alert(msg)
                return result;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>

    <form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
        <table width="50%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td id="name">Name</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="subject">Subject</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick= return "validateForm()";  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: The `return` should be inside the quotes.

Comment: Yes. I tried to do that. The error is still the same.

Comment: Of course. The quotes around `name` and `subject` are invalid characters in JavaScript, your validation function has a parameter `document` which takes priority over the global `document` and is undefined on your function call because you don't pass anything to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has couple of syntax errors. I have removed that.
here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syFU9/4/) link

```
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
    <form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
        <table width="50%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td id="name">Name</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="subject">Subject</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick= " return validateForm();"  /><!--js function inside quotes-->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

<script>
//function had illegal parameter
function validateForm() {
            var result = true;
            var msg = "";
            if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == "") {
                msg += "You must enter your name \n";
                document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
                document.getElementById('name').style.color = "red";
                 // document.getElementById(‘name’).style.color = "red";--->Id should be in quotes
                result = false;
            }
            if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value == "") {
                msg += "You must enter the subject \n";
                document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
                document.getElementById('subject').style.color = "red";
                // document.getElementById(‘subject’).style.color = "red";--->Id should be in quotes
                result = false;
            }
            if (msg == "") {
                return result;
            } {
                alert(msg);
                return result;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, a "couple" mistakes. +1. If OP is learning though, it could be nice to explain a bit of what was fixed and why. I just added a lacking semi-colon after the `alert` as the whole code is semi-colon'd and leaving it for ASI would be just plain laziness.

Comment: Oh my god. I have no idea how you've achieved in 20 minutes what all the computing teachers in my school have failed to do in the last couple of months, but thank you so much.

Comment: @user1656455 i have edited my answer to show your mistakes as Fabrício Matté pointed out

Comment: @FabrícioMatté i have edited my answer to show OP mistakes as you said :-)

Comment: Yup looks good. `=]` The quotes were mostly due to the OCR software and the book font I guess.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm sorry, but one more thing: what is an illegal parameter? It came out on the debugging console...

Comment: Not now. Before you fixed it... You say that the function had an illegal parameter, and so did the console. And I'm just completely new to this and had no idea what an "illegal parameter" was...

Comment: @user1656455 your onclick function was not passing any parameters but your js function was defined to accept parameters, hence the conflict. http://www.htmlite.com/JS008.php